# Failed to run stanford CS107 assignment files on my Mac or PC, help~

Tags: c++

I was auditing Stanford cs107 and unable to get the assignment files (which could be found here http://see.stanford.edu/see/materials/icsppcs107/assignments.aspx) working on my Mac or PC. I tried to run it on Ubuntu through VM, it didn't work either.

In assignment 1, the file rsg-sample-linux shows not executable, unlike it is on the assignment PDF file. After I used chmod to change it to be executable, the terminal on my Mac says "cannot execute binary file", and Ubuntu says "no such file directory" something like that.

I really want to go through all the assignments while auditing this class

Thanks!

Comment: on ubuntu did you execute `./rsg-sample-linux`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since these are binary files there is no guarantee that they run on your system. `rsg-sample-linux` is for 32 Bit systems, so if you have a 64 Bit system and missing some compatibility library, it won't work.

Therefore you cannot avoid typing in `make` and built the `rsg` on your own.

Comment: I have run it on 32-bit Ubuntu under VM on my PC, and switched my Mac to 32-bit, neither of these work.

Comment: Nothing to thank for, if it's useful don't forget to upvote or accept the answer.

Comment: I have this same problem. Can someone give me more details on how to get this working.

Comment: As i already said, you'll have to build this on your own using make. Should be somewhere documented in the assignments, I believe.