# CS107 Assignment Files

Tags: c++, c, macos, unix

I'm trying to run the Stanford CS107 Assignment files on my mac but whenever I try to run the binary files I get an error 'Permission denied'.  If I chmod the file so I have execute permissions I get an error that says 'cannot execute binary file'.

How can I execute these files?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Failed to run stanford CS107 assignment files on my Mac or PC, help~](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558345/failed-to-run-stanford-cs107-assignment-files-on-my-mac-or-pc-help).

Comment: Jesse, he posted on there 30 minutes ago. I think he has a different issue. maybe.

Comment: I think the problem is the same but that question doesn't provide any answers. I haven't run the files on a linux system though, maybe that is a requirement.

Comment: You may have to pass it some arguments or something via command-line. Have you tried contacting the professor?

Comment: Haven't tried contacting the professor, I'm not enrolled at stanford. The course is available free online at http://see.stanford.edu/see/courseinfo.aspx?coll=2d712634-2bf1-4b55-9a3a-ca9d470755ee

Comment: What is the precise name and download URL of one of the files you are trying to run?

Comment: Heres a link to the zip file for the assignment.  I'm trying to run 'imdb-test-linux' that is inside that folder. http://see.stanford.edu/materials/icsppcs107/assn-2-six-degrees.zip

Comment: The answer is to build the executable yourself. The linked data already comes with a makefile, so just use that.

Comment: The make file builds an imdb-test binary that I can run (although i get a segmentation fault: 11 error) but I think that might be because I haven't started the assignment. I'm a beginner when it comes to this stuff but I don't think I can use the make file to help me run imdb-test-linux which is meant to show you the desired output for the assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't run the imdb-test-linux binary because all the source files aren't given.  To get the imdb-test file to run there was a problem in the imdb-utils.h file.  The code uses

```
const char *ostype = getenv("OSTYPE");
```

Which returns Null on my mac for some reason. To fix the problem, in the 'determinePathToData' function inside the imdb-utils.h file just return the directory where you have placed the data files.

run 'make imdb-test' and it should run.

Hope this helps someone :)